# Extracting certain portion of a geotiff with node-gdal

Tags: gdal, node-gdal

I use node server. And I want send coordinates of an area then extract related portion of the geotiff file (dem) using node-gdal.

Is it possible to do this with node-gdal?

Answer (score 1):

Gdal_translate allows you to export to another raster, clipping on the way out by either pixel/lines or geo-referenced co-ordinates:

**-srcwin xoff yoff xsize ysize:**
    Selects a subwindow from the source image for copying based on pixel/line location.

**-projwin ulx uly lrx lry:**
    Selects a subwindow from the source image for copying (like -srcwin) but with the corners given in georeferenced coordinates (by default expressed in the SRS of the dataset. Can be changed with -projwin_srs). Note: in GDAL 2.1.0 and 2.1.1, using -projwin with coordinates not aligned with pixels will result in a sub-pixel shift. This has been corrected in later versions. When selecting non-nearest neighbour resampling, starting with GDAL 2.1.0, sub-pixel accuracy is however used to get better results.

Comment: Thank you, they are the solutions in shell. How can we do these in node server with node-gdal?